# Swift 2.0 - How to return tuple from a string input

Tags: tuples, swift2

I am learning to write Swift 2.0 code with treehouse. I am trying to write a code where you would enter either "Eiffel Tower," "Great Pyramid," "Sydney Opera House" and the function would output the longitude and latitude coordinates. I am having trouble having the function return the coordinates - any help would be appreciated!

```
func getTowerCoordinates (location: String) -> (lat: Double, lon: Double) {
switch location {
case "Eiffel Tower": (48.8582, 2.2945)
case "Great Pyramid": (29.9792, 31.1344)
case "Sydney Opera House": (33.8587, 151.2140)
default: (0,0)
}
return (lat, lon)
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should create a variable where you could save the data and then return it.

```
func getTowerCoordinates (location: String) -> (lat: Double, lon: Double) {
    var coordinates: (lat: Double, lon: Double)

    switch location {
    case "Eiffel Tower":
        coordinates = (48.8582, 2.2945)
        break
    case "Great Pyramid":
        coordinates = (29.9792, 31.1344)
        break
    case "Sydney Opera House":
        coordinates = (33.8587, 151.2140)
        break
    default:
        coordinates = (0,0)
    }

    return coordinates
}
```

or easier:

```
func getTowerCoordinates (location: String) -> (lat: Double, lon: Double) {
    switch location {
    case "Eiffel Tower":
        return (48.8582, 2.2945)
    case "Great Pyramid":
        return (29.9792, 31.1344)
    case "Sydney Opera House":
        return (33.8587, 151.2140)
    default:
        return (0, 0)
    }
}
```

`(lat: Double, lon: Double)` is resulting type of the function, where you tag your first element of the tuple as `lat` and the second one as `lon`.

Afterwards, you can write something like that:

```
let (lat, lon) = getTowerCoordinates("Eiffel Tower") 
print(lat)
print(lon)
```

or

```
let coordinates = getTowerCoordinates("Eiffel Tower")
print(coordinates.lat)
print(coordinates.lon)
```

which is the same